# How to skip 'noise' in a JSON object stream?

Tags: json, parsing, go, io

Trying to get the following code to skip parse error *noise* in a JSON data object stream. Basically I want it to skip the `ERROR: ...` lines and continue onto the next parseable record.

`json.Decoder` has a limited set of [methods](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) - so it's unclear how to move the decoder's index forward (say a byte at a time) to move past the noise.

`io.Reader` has methods to skip to say the end of the line (or at least try skipping a character at time) - but doing such operations does not (understandably) affect the `json.Decoder`'s seek state.

Is there a clean way to do this?

https://play.golang.org/p/riIDh9g1Rx

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "strings"
        "time"
)

type event struct {
        T    time.Time
        Desc string
}

var jsonStream = ` 
{"T":"2017-11-02T16:00:00-04:00","Desc":"window opened"}
{"T":"2017-11-02T16:30:00-04:00","Desc":"window closed"}
{"T":"2017-11-02T16:41:34-04:00","Desc":"front door opened"}
ERROR: retrieving event 1234
{"T":"2017-11-02T16:41:40-04:00","Desc":"front door closed"}
`

func main() {
        jsonReader := strings.NewReader(jsonStream)
        decodeStream := json.NewDecoder(jsonReader)

        i := 0
        for decodeStream.More() {
                i++ 
                var ev event
                if err := decodeStream.Decode(&ev); err != nil {
                        fmt.Println("parse error: %s", err)
                        break
                }   
                fmt.Printf("%3d: %+v\n", i, ev) 
        }   
}
```

got:

```
  1: {T:2017-11-02 16:00:00 -0400 -0400 Desc:window opened}
  2: {T:2017-11-02 16:30:00 -0400 -0400 Desc:window closed}
  3: {T:2017-11-02 16:41:34 -0400 -0400 Desc:front door opened}
parse error: %s invalid character 'E' looking for beginning of value
```

want:

```
  1: {T:2017-11-02 16:00:00 -0400 -0400 Desc:window opened}
  2: {T:2017-11-02 16:30:00 -0400 -0400 Desc:window closed}
  3: {T:2017-11-02 16:41:34 -0400 -0400 Desc:front door opened}
  4: {T:2017-11-02 16:41:40 -0400 -0400 Desc:front door closed}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the "correct" way to do this, as the stream itself *is not valid JSON* (even without the errors, a JSON document must have a single root entry, this is a series of root objects which is not valid), would be to pre-parse into individual, valid JSON documents, and unmarshal each separately. Read the stream line-by-line using e.g. [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner), discard the non-JSON lines, and `Unmarshal` the others as normal.

See working example here: https://play.golang.org/p/DZrAVmzwr-

Comment: for simplicity, I used a string, but in practice the data is via a web-service stream (not owned by me), so there is no _document_ per se. I want to parse the parseable data and skip any garbage non-parseable bytes. Each records is on a line - so skipping to the end of the line ('\n') would be acceptable solution.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a string or from a web service. The process is the same, and a Scanner will still work. See the playground example in my edit.

Comment: My comment was related to your statement of this being invalid JSON (parse error aside). A stream of valid JSON objects is valid to a _Decoder_.

Comment: It may be accepted by *some* decoders, but it is not valid JSON and therefor you can't reasonably expect *every* decoder to accept it. That's why it must first be preprocessed into invidual, valid JSON documents before attempting to decode it.

Comment: http-sse uses individual records. They don't begin the JSON stream with '['.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the bufio suggestion @Adrian.  Is there any issue with reading by line - if say a '\n' appears in a valid JSON object - and cause a line to be half-read?

Comment: It certainly could, yes; there are a lot of potential edge cases here depending on what might be in the data stream. You could look for the closing brace, if you know it won't be in the text in an object. If you have to account for all possible content you'll basically end up writing your own parser. Go's JSON decoder is a JSON decoder, not a server sent events parser - you might look for a specific library for that, in case this is a problem already solved by a 3rd party.

Answer (score 1):

While not very clean, you could use the `Buffered` method of a JSON decoder to get access to the underlying reader, which should still be pointing at the byte that caused the error, and wrap it in a buffered reader when necessary. Then you can read individual bytes until you encounter a valid JSON start-object byte `{` and unread that byte (at least 1 byte can be unread in any implementation) to push the byte back onto the buffered stream.

[Playground link for code below](https://play.golang.org/p/8G-ddt8qSq)

```
...
decodeLoop:
    for decodeStream.More() {
        i++
        var ev event
        if err := decodeStream.Decode(&ev); err != nil {
            r := decodeStream.Buffered()
            br, ok := r.(*bufio.Reader)
            if !ok {
                br = bufio.NewReader(r)
            }
            for {
                b, err := br.ReadByte()
                if err != nil {
                    // Whether EOF or not, there's nothing left to do except
                    // break the loop to trigger the "parse error" statement.
                    break
                }
                // A (potentially) valid JSON object was found;
                // create a new decoder associated with the same decodeStream var
                // using the new buffered reader and continue decoding.
                if b == '{' {
                    br.UnreadByte()
                    decodeStream = json.NewDecoder(br)
                    continue decodeLoop
                }
            }
            fmt.Println("parse error: %s", err)
            break
        }
        ...
```

However, [this is not bulletproof as-is](https://play.golang.org/p/UtXZWtAI7Q).

IMHO, the proper way to handle this requires that you receive a single JSON array of JSON objects, allowing you to handle manual tokenization of each JSON object that represents an `event` by providing an `UnmarshalJSON` method with an `*event` method receiver, but if you cannot get that, then this doesn't matter, and you'll need to modify the provided solution to make it work as necessary, assuming that is possible. One possible remedy is to set a flag and unset it when a valid JSON object is detected:

```
    objectDetected := false
    i := 0
decodeLoop:
    ...
                if b == '{' {
                    // If we already encountered an object and found ourselves here again,
                    // it's not really a valid JSON object.
                    if objectDetected {
                        break
                    }
                    objectDetected = true
                    br.UnreadByte()
                    ...
        fmt.Printf("%3d: %+v\n", i, ev)
        objectDetected = false
    } // decode loop end
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/axf_bLK-3d)

Comment: this is actually what I wanted to achieve: if there's a parse error, move the seek pointer 1 byte at a time until a valid record is read. Seeking just on '{' would not necessarily work as the 'noise' may include a '{'. So nice use of `bufio.Reader` and `Decoder.Buffered` to achieve that.

Comment: FYI: the JSON "stream", while static in the playground example, in reality it would come from a HTTP-SSE web-service (outside of our control) and need to be processed in realtime. So expecting the objects in their "entirety" is not possible.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn&#39;t certain if you had access to modify the service or not. Your stream is similar to that of the i3status program on Linux, which outputs a single object containing version info, followed by an infinite/incomplete array of objects containing info to print on the status bar. The only difference between your case and that one is that there is only one lone object before the stream prints the objects of interest. A known abnormal item at the start of the stream can be skipped, but abnormalities throughout the stream is a bit more complex.